# Hiding Content Based on Content of URL String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a certain fieldset with an id of "retail" based on if the URL has 'studio' as a part of it. The URL would read as follows:

/island-careers/studio/accounting/accountant/apply.html

Here is my script I have written up but I can't seem to get it to recognize if 'studio' is in the URL.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var path = window.location.pathname;

        console.log(path);

        var split = window.location.href.split('/');

        console.log(split);

        console.log(split[4]);

      if (split[4] === 'studio') {
          jQuery('#retail').css('display, none');
      }  
    });
</script>
```

The "console.log(split[4]); was to find the location of 'studio' in the array. There must be something wrong with my IF statement I guess. I also tried this method but it didn't work for me either:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var path = window.location.pathname;

        console.log(path);


      if (path.indexOf('studio') >= 0) {
          jQuery('#retail').css('display, none')
      }  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the output on the console log for split[4]?

Comment: It comes out to 'studio' I left out the http:// www.mywebsite.com/ part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery line to change the CSS should be:

```
 jQuery('#retail').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that. Thank you for the help. Sometimes all you need is an extra set of eyes